# Ĉu estas bona traduko por la angla vorto «gate»?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiel oni povas traduki la anglan vorton «gate», ekzemple por priskribi ĉi tiun objekton (la pordon en la barilo):

[image: gate en Minecraft]

La vortaroj de Lernu kaj John Wells havas *pordego*, sed al mi tio ŝajnas ne taŭga ĉar tiu pordo fakte estas pli malgranda ol normala pordo. Eble tio estas ĉefe por io kiel la [Brandenburga pordego](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburga_pordego).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pordego* is a large door for closing off a gateway - this is often appropriate for large gates in exterior walls.

*Barila pordo* is a small door through a fence.

*Pordejo* or is a gateway, and seems appropriate for the picture, since it doesn't look like it can be closed.

Comment: The picture is probably a bad example because it can be closed even though it doesn’t look like it. _Barila pordo_ seems like a good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Now that you say mention that detail, it also looks smaller than I initially imagined. I thought that was a giant brick wall with pillars, but I now think it's supposed to represent something closer to a post-and-rail fence.

Answer (score 4):

You could say Pordo.  The [Wiktionary](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/pordo) mentions that pordo could refer to a gate.  In Spanish, the equivalent word "puerta" can be used for gate.

Answer (score 0):

> Pordo - Malfermaĵo en muro de **urbo**, konstruaĵo, ĉambro...
>
> Pordego - Ĉefa pordo de domo, de fortika **urbo**, por paso de veturiloj...

www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/